# SwiftUI - present sheet programatically

Tags: modal-dialog, swiftui

I would like to have a modal sheet appear with several options for the user to choose from. (The share sheet is a perfect example.) When the user makes a selection, the option sheet disappears and a second sheet appears with the selected option. In the share sheet example, if the user selects print, the share sheet slides down and the print sheet pops up.

I can get the option sheet to appear easily enough. But I haven't figured out how to get the second sheet to appear. I tried attaching the sheet to an empty view and then used UserDefaults to set the bool that activates the second sheet. Nothing.

**First Sheet**

```
Button(action: {
   UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: showSelectedOption)
   showOptionForm = true
}) {
   Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
}
.sheet(isPresented: $showOptionForm) {
   OptionView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
})
```

**SecondSheet**

```
EmptyView()
   .sheet(isPresented: $showSelectedOption) {
      SelectedOptionView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
}
```

I tried setting the bool shown below in .onAppear, but it does not get called when a modal sheet is dismissed. Is there a way to tell when a view is no longer being covered by a sheet? In UIKit it would have been presentationControllerDidDismiss(_:). Of course, this is assuming that my idea to attach the second sheet to an empty view is even workable.

```
let showSelectedOption = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showSelectedOption")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is demo of possible approach - you activate second sheet in `onDismiss` of first one. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
struct DemoTwoSheets: View {
    @State private var firstSheet = false
    @State private var secondSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Tap") { self.firstSheet = true }
                .sheet(isPresented: $firstSheet, onDismiss: {
                    self.secondSheet = true
                }) {
                    Text("First sheet")
                }
            EmptyView()
                .sheet(isPresented: $secondSheet) {
                    Text("Second sheet")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is an alternate which works for SwiftUI 1.0 as well. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 and Xcode 12b5 / iOS 14.

```
struct DemoTwoSheets: View {
    @State private var firstSheet = false
    @State private var secondSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Tap") { self.firstSheet = true }
                .sheet(isPresented: $firstSheet, onDismiss: {
                    self.secondSheet = true
                }) {
                    Text("First sheet")
                }
                .background(Color.clear
                    .sheet(isPresented: $secondSheet) {
                        Text("Second sheet")
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Xcode 11.6 / iOS 13.6. I marked it correct since it will work when the next version of iOS is released. Maybe I can figure out an alternative using an ObservableObject...

Comment: See update with variant that works on iOS 13 as well.

Comment: One follow up question - when I use views with dismiss buttons, the second sheet can't be dismissed unless you swipe down. I tried using a presentationMode variable as well as a binding variable without success. I know this is a workaround for iOS13 but do you think there's a workaround way to dismiss the second sheet as well? Thanks!